# C# 7 ref return for reference types

Tags: c#, .net, clr, pass-by-reference, c#-7.0

I'm going through some code that uses the new features of C# 7 and uses the ref locals & returns feature.

It seems pretty straight forward for `value-types` where the ref local variable gets a reference (to the actual storage), and updating that updates the value of the original item.

A little explanation will help in understanding how memory references work in case of ref locals for the `reference-types`. I'm pointing to the last line of the code below:

```
// A simple class
public class CoolClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public CoolClass(string name, int id) => (Name, Id) = (name, id);
}

//Dummy method that returns first element with Id > 100
public CoolClass GetSpecialItem_Old(CoolClass[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        if (arr[i].Id > 100)
        {
            return arr[i];
        }
    throw new Exception("Not found");
}

//Same as the other one, but returns by ref C# 7
public ref CoolClass GetSpecialItem_New(CoolClass[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        if (arr[i].Id > 100)
        {
            return ref arr[i];
        }
    throw new Exception("Not found");
}

public void TestMethod()
{
    var arr = new CoolClass[]
    {
        new CoolClass("A", 10),
        new CoolClass("B", 101),
        new CoolClass("C", 11)
    };

    var byVal = GetSpecialItem_Old(arr); //gets back arr[1]
    byVal.Name = "byVal"; //arr[1] = { "byVal", 101 }
    byVal = new CoolClass("newByVal", 25); //arr[1] = { "byVal", 101 }

    ref var byRef = ref GetSpecialItem_New(arr); //gets back arr[1]
    byRef.Name = "byRef"; //arr[1] = { "byRef", 101 }
    //Here it has a different behaviour 
    byRef = new CoolClass("newByRef", 50); //arr[1] = { "newByRef", 50 }
}
```

Comment: `ref var byRef` is basically the same reference to `arr[1]`, so if you `byRef = new ...` you "actually" do `arr[1] = new ...` under the hood.

Answer (score 22):

The fact that the original designers of C# named the feature "ref" was in my opinion a bad idea. It leads one to confuse reference types and "ref" parameters / returns.  The better way to think of "ref" is "alias".  That is, ref *gives you another name for an existing variable*.

In your program, `byRef` is another name for `arr[1]` **regardless of whether `arr[1]` is of value type or reference type**. If `arr[1]` is a string variable (remember, **array elements are variables; you can change them**) then `byref` is a string variable also, and it is the *same* string variable with a different name.

Note that `arr` is also a variable; if you change the value of `arr`, then `byRef` does not come along for the ride.  It remains an alias for the same slot of the same array, regardless of the value of `arr`.

So when you say

```
ref var byRef = ref GetSpecialItem_New(arr); //gets back arr[1]
```

Then

```
byRef.Name = "byRef";
```

is exactly the same as

```
arr[1].Name = "byRef";
```

And when you say

```
byRef = new CoolClass("newByRef", 50);
```

That's exactly the same as

```
arr[1] = new CoolClass("newByRef", 50);
```

With the caveat that if you changed `arr` after assigning `byRef`, you'd still have an alias to the *original* `arr[1]`.

Again: `byRef` is *simply another way to spell `arr[1]`*, such that it always uses the value of `arr` that it had when `byRef` was assigned.  It's *not* different for value types or reference types.

In contrast, `byVal` is NOT an alias for `arr[1]`.  It is a *second* variable that has a *copy* of the contents of `arr[1]`. When you assign to `byVal` you are not assigning to `arr[1]`.  You're assigning to `byVal`, which is a *different* variable.

The *contents* of `arr[1]` is a *reference*, and that *reference* is copied to `byVal`, a separate storage location entirely.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation Eric. The points `better way to think of "ref" is "alias"` and `such that it always uses the value of arr that it had when byRef was assigned` make it much easier to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting question is how you can force the [`Ref returns and ref locals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) to behave as you would like when testing?
You can do this by mocking the `GetSpecialItem_New` method with [JustMock](https://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx).

Here is how the method from the question looks like:

```
public class Foo
{
    //Same as the other one, but returns by ref C# 7
    public ref CoolClass GetSpecialItem_New(CoolClass[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            if (arr[i].Id > 100)
            {
                return ref arr[i];
            }
        throw new Exception("Not found");
    }
}
```

And here is how you can mock that method to return the desired result for isolated testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCoolClass()
{
    var expected = new CoolClass("42", 42);

    var arr = new CoolClass[]
    {
        new CoolClass("A", 10),
        new CoolClass("B", 101),
        new CoolClass("C", 11)
    };

    // Arrange
    var sut = Mock.Create<Foo>();
    Mock.Arrange(sut, s => s.GetSpecialItem_New(arr)).Returns(LocalRef.WithValue(expected).Handle).OccursOnce();

    // Act
    ref CoolClass actual = ref sut.GetSpecialItem_New(arr);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Here is a [help article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/advanced-usage/ref-return-mocking.html) explaining in details the testing approach.

Disclaimer. I am one of the developers responsible for [JustMock](https://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx).