# why "return ref a[0]" doesn't change the original array?

Tags: c#, function, reference, method-call, return-by-reference

I plan to return a reference of a value in an array (and manipulate it), however, when I pass the array in method(), the result is not what I want.

And I also curious about the fact that I can't use DEBUG monitor to query the address of `&a` in `method()` stack.

Any one could help me with the correct use of `return ref`?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int?[] s = new int?[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var q = method(ref s);
    q = 999;
    Console.WriteLine("s0 is " + s[0].ToString());
}

static ref int? method(ref int?[] a)
{
    a[1] = 888;
    return ref a[0];
}
```

Comment: `ref var q = ref method(ref s);` • See [Ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals) and [Ref Returns, Ref Locals, and how to use them](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/128/c-sharp-7-ref-returns-ref-locals-and-how-to-use-them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't C# support the return of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339602/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-the-return-of-references) and [C# 7 ref return for reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310345/c-sharp-7-ref-return-for-reference-types)

Comment: See this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `q` is not a ref local. It is just a regular variable. You are also not saying `ref` before the method call, so this is just a regular by-value assignment. Because of these reasons, `q` is not an alias of `a[0]`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals) gives a similar example:

> Assume the `GetContactInformation` method is declared as a `ref return`:
>
> ```
> public ref Person GetContactInformation(string fname, string lname)
> ```
>
> A by-value assignment reads the value of a variable and assigns it to a new variable:
>
> ```
> Person p = contacts.GetContactInformation("Brandie", "Best");
> ```
>
> The preceding assignment declares `p` as a local variable. Its initial value is copied from reading the value returned by `GetContactInformation`. Any future assignments to `p` will not change the value of the variable returned by `GetContactInformation`. The variable `p` is no longer an alias to the variable returned.

To fix this, you would add `ref` before `var` to make `q` a ref local, and also add `ref` before the call to make it a  by-ref assignment:

```
ref var q = ref method(ref s);
```

Comment: really thanks for underlining the key part of official document!